# Fluent NHibernate: How to map a db integer to a datetime column?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class

```
public class Site {
  public DateTime SiteMonth {get; set;}
}
```

in the database the SiteMonth is represented as an integer in yyyymm format.

Is there a way to map this in NHibernate without introducing a new property on my Site class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - make a simple `IUserType` that maps between your integer format and a DateTime. Then set the `type` attribute on the `property` element to the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of that user type.

Ayende has an [example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Entities-dependencies-best-practices.aspx) on how to implement a user type.

Oh yeah, and if you are using Fluent NHibernate to do your mappings, you can do it like this:

```
Map(d => d.MyFunkyWeirdLegacyDateTime)
    .SetAttribute("type", typeof(MyCustomDateTime).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

Comment: `CustomTypeIs<MyCustomDateTime>()` is the preferred method, instead of `SetAttribute`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! Fluent NHibernate is smashing, by the way :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was just in the Fluent NHibernate Wiki and came across [this](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/AutoMappingTypeConventions), which is in the AutoMapping conventions, but in the Fluent Mapping Conventions section it mentioned that the AutoMapping Conventions will work for Fluent Mapping as well.